# L'Hospital rule for $\frac{0}{0}\cdot\frac{a}{0}$

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

Is there a solution to use the rule of L'Hospital for a boundary value problem like

$$\lim_{x\to1}\left(\dfrac{x^{2}-1}{x-1}\cdot\dfrac{a}{x^{3}-1}\right)$$

where $a> 0$ ?

I know how to solve $\dfrac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ but not how to deal with the other term.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The question is unclear. Perhaps it would help to include a specific example and your attempts to solve it.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you are getting a form like that?

Comment: Your limit has a very definite answer $\infty$. Why do you need a L'Hospital ?

Comment: I thought the solution will be a convergence instead of divergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to solve the following by L'Hopital?
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\cdot\frac{a}{x^3-1}\right)
$$

> "...I know how to solve $(x^2−1)/(x−1)$ but not how to deal with the other term."

I believe here that you mean that you would understand an example like
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\right)=\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)
$$
where $f(x)=(x^2-1)$ and $g(x)=(x-1)$ and be able to solve that.

So why is the other example throwing you off?  I assume that you are doing the following:
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\cdot\frac{a}{x^3-1}\right)=\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot\frac{a}{x^3-1}\right)
$$
and are now at a complete loss as to what to do with that "third term".

The problem is simply that you chose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ poorly!  For L'Hopital to work, there can't be "another term" left over. A properly chosen $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ pair should leave nothing left over.

Try instead $f(x)=(x^2-1)\cdot a$ and $g(x)=(x-1)\cdot(x^3-1)$.

Comment: Yeah you're right with your assumption. It was a little bit unclear formulated: I have no problem with solving it in the way you describe it. My problem was that I didn't know if it is right to use L'Hospital for the whole expression. Now I know it :)

Comment: @maxwell1902 Also, do be aware that this isn't the "only choice" possible for f(x) and g(x) - one doesn't need to cut specifically across the numerator/denominator line.  One could alternatively choose $f(x)=(x^2-1)/(x-1)$ and $g(x)=(x^3-1)/a$ or a variety of other things.  Sometimes the work in calculating the derivatives f' or g' is minimized by choosing an unintuitive split rather than simply using the intuitive numerator and denominator split.

Comment: ok thank you I will be aware of it

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{0}{0} * \frac{a}{0} = \frac{0*a}{0*0}$, in which you can then use L'Hopital's rule.

In your example, we have $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1} \frac{a}{x^3-1} = \frac{a(x^2-1)}{(x-1)(x^3-1)}$. This is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: Ok, if this is mathematically correct, then I'm able to solve it. Thank you